# How to receive images from Android and iOS to Rails 3.2.8 using multipart and Carrierwave?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave

How should my controller action look like when receiving image from an Android or iPhone?

My image model is the following:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :file_path

  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :file_path, FileUploader
end
```

The current controller:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:upload]

  def upload
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    # I have no idea what else I have to do...
  end
end
```

I'm in doubt how Carrierwave magically save the files to the server and what should I do in the controller to receive that Post.

Answer (score 0):

`file_path` is now a field in your model. This means when you pass that field into your controller when creating a new model, it will automatically pick that up and save it.

Your multipart file data should be send as `params[:image][:file_path]` when creating a new Model, assuming the `create` method in your controller is being passed `params[:image]`.